# What do I need to specify in order for pandas to_csv to keep leading zeros

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I have a excel file and I read into a dataframe.  I'd like to output this df to CSV file. But one of the columns (labeled `id`) in CSV file are integer like 1 ,but wanna output string like"0001"with leading zeros.
Every time I try to output the file, it interprets this column as integer and removes the leading zeros.  I need all leading zeros.

I've tried

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(<path&filenane>,convertors={"id":object})
df.to_csv(<path&filename>)
```

CSV file I'd like to see

```
id,name,birthday
0001,smith,1980/01/01
dtypes =object,object,object
```

But now

```
id,name,birthday
1,smith,1980/01/01
dtypes=int,object,object
```

Comment: I honestly do not understand what you're asking here, what has input id = '0001' mean here?

Comment: Are you saying something like `to-csv` is treating `0001` as an int, but you don't want it to do that?

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and answering!! This question is pandas.to_csv problem.In case of using pandas.to_excel,I'm able to output str values like "0001",but in case of use pandas.to_csv, output int values like "1" not leading zero

Answer (score 0):

You can control the type and format of input columns with the `converters` parameter.  The following example accomplishes what you're after.

- Make sure to use your `filename` in place of `StringIO(txt)`
- The converter parameter takes a dictionary with the key being the name of the column and the value being a callable.  In this case we use the string object class as the callable.  It will apply this callable ("function" sort of) to the column thus keeping the leading zeros.

---

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """id,name,birthday
0001,smith,1980/01/01
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), converters=dict(id=str))

df

     id   name    birthday
0  0001  smith  1980/01/01
```

Comment: OK I re-read the question, I thought the data was an excel sheet but it's a csv, anyway I think this question is a dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293810/import-pandas-dataframe-column-as-string-not-int