# Python - How to import strings of numbers with 0 in front

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, integer

I'm importing data from excel with pandas. A column of my dataframe contains some strings of numbers with 0 as the first character and python transforms it into integer. For example 0700 is placed 700. How to not alter the value and consider it as a string with 0 in front?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293810/import-pandas-dataframe-column-as-string-not-int

Answer (score 0):

By using the 'converters' parameter on your dataframe statement, e.g.

```
df = pd.read_excel('*workbook name here',sheetname='*sheet name here',header=0,converters={'*integer column name here':str})
```