# How do I make pandas `read_csv` to recognize quoted columns as strings (without quotes)

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a CSV, named `a.csv` that looks like this:

```
foo,bar
aaa,"1234"
bbb,"5678"
```

I'd like to read in the `bar` column as strings, as indicated by the double-quotes.

However, when I run the following:

```
d = pd.read_csv("a.csv")
print(d.dtypes)
```

It returns:

```
foo    object
bar     int64
dtype: object
```

I've tried various combinations of parameters: `quoting`, `quotechar`, but can't seem to get `bar` recognized as strings (i.e. having `object` rather than `int64` as its `dtype`).

Is it possible to achieve this without explicitly specifying the column type via the `dtype` parameter?

**EDIT**: I don't believe the referenced question answers my question. That reference describes how strings are stored as objects, but it doesn't explicitly answer why a quoted column, i.e. `bar`, is NOT casted to strings. Nor does it answer how to get a string column out of `bar`.

**EDIT 2**: I should clarify that perhaps I don't care to return a `str` type for the `bar` column but rather I **DO NOT** want it to return an `int64` type for `bar`. It is a bit odd to me that despite there being explicit quotes around foo column entries, Pandas chooses to ignore the quotes and select `int64` for `bar`'s type.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate, but I am unsure why. I provided justification for how this is unique in the EDIT section above.

Comment: try: `df['bar'] = df['bar'].astype(str)` to do the conversion you are looking for.

Comment: @EvanW. That won't work. @Tom I proposed the duplicate because the answers there explain clearly that strings are stored ad objects. That means that the `dtype` of strings, when stored inside a pandas dataframe, is `object.` Stop. There is nothing you can do, no way to cast it back as strings. However, If you get back the element from the pandas dataframe, e.g. if you do `df['bar'].tolist()` to get a normal python list, that will be a list of strings.

Comment: @Valentino, what are you looking to do with the non-object dtype column that you need it to be cast as strings?

Comment: @EvanW. In that case, your answer works. But the `dtype` will be `object`, not `string`. The OP is asking how to get a `dtype = string` and this is not possible.

Comment: @Valentino, I got you mixed up with the OP. My apologies.

Comment: @Tom, If you check the type of "1234", it display as class of str. So python consider "1234" as datatype of string. However when you read the csv file python automatically converted it as int64. If you want this field to treat as string you need to explicitly mentioned it as below.
d=pd.read_csv("a.csv", dtype={'bar': str})
print(d.dtypes) Hope this answer your question

Comment: Please refer this links, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293810/import-pandas-dataframe-column-as-string-not-int

Comment: @EvanW thank you but I was looking for a way to perform it directly in the read_csv call and not after

Comment: @Valentino please see Edit 2 for additional follow-up and clarification

Comment: @SUN I guess my question is WHY does it choose INT64 despite there being quotes? I understand I can cast with the dtype input parameter but I was surprised it needed to be explicit given the input contains quotes. What kind of INT64 has quotes?

Comment: @Valentino @WeNYoBen I think the question is more about handling quotes in `read_csv` rather than making columns into strings. I would say it is not a duplicate and I propose to reopen it.

Comment: Now is clearer what the OP is asking. Then use `df = pd.read_csv(path_of_file,  quoting=3)`. The `quoting=3` will do the trick. See [read_csv docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for more details on the `quoting` parameter. However this will keep also the quoting characters.

Comment: Use of Quoting, make it datatype as object, but do we really want to see the ' " ' as part of data. I believe, column should have only number.

Comment: @SUN agree. I had assumed the quotes in each entry would signify the contents signify a string is enclosed.

Comment: The interpretation of quotes is controlled by the `quoting` parameter as defined in the `csv` module https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents (the definitions are at the end of the section).

Comment: Usually whenever there is special character then only it wrapped in Quotes else it is plain text and that could be the idea behind open_csv ( in case of alphanumeric or special characters it treat as object whereas numeric it implicit conversion int64.)

Comment: So let's recap here. (1) If I have quotes around the `foo` column entries: I can read it in as an `object` type with `quoting=3`, but it keeps the quotes. (2) If I don't have quotes around the object, there is no direct parameter in `read_csv` (other than explicit `dtype=` setting) that allows it to know that it is an object and not an integer in this case. Is that correct?

Comment: According to my research and investigation, yes I agree with you.