# python Panda float number get rounded while converting to string

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scientific-notation

I have this CSV file

```
id,adset_id,source
1,,google
2,23843814084680281,facebook
3,,google
4,23843814088700279,facebook
5,23843704830370464,facebook
```

My problem is when I am trying to read it with panda since I can not pass the schema panda infer the schema for `adset_id` column to be float64 (because of NaN value)

So if I write this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/test/Desktop/float.csv')
print(df)
```

I will get scientific notation for `adset_id`
result:

```
   id      adset_id    source
0   1           NaN    google
1   2  2.384381e+16  facebook
2   3           NaN    google
3   4  2.384381e+16  facebook
4   5  2.384370e+16  facebook
```

I could not find any way to fix this so I tried to do a hack and convert this number to String. But in order to do that, I need to convert it to `int64` first and after that convert it to string.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/test/Desktop/float.csv')

df = df.fillna({'adset_id':-1})
df['adset_id'] = df['adset_id'].astype('int64')
df['adset_id'] = df['adset_id'].astype('str')
df['adset_id'].replace('-1', np.NaN, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

The result is:

```
   id           adset_id    source
0   1                NaN    google
1   2  23843814084680280  facebook
2   3                NaN    google
3   4  23843814088700280  facebook
4   5  23843704830370464  facebook
```

As you can see 2 of my `adset_id` get rounded:
`23843814084680281` -> `23843814084680280`
`23843814088700279` -> `23843814088700280`

I just want to be able to read this CSV to panda data frame and don't get   `adset_id` as scientific notation, any solution would be appreciated

Comment: Use `pd.read_csv('/Users/test/Desktop/float.csv', dtype={'adset_id': object})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import pandas dataframe column as string not int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293810/import-pandas-dataframe-column-as-string-not-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Look at the `dtype` argument. You can set a dictionary of dtypes to ensure it is read as a string.

```
df = pd.read_csv('PATH_TO_CSV.csv', dtype={'adset_id':str})
```

You can also look at the `na_values`, `keep_default_na`, and `na_filter` arguments to help with handling NULLs

Answer (score 0):

The "conversion" to scientific notation is occurring in `pandas` in the way it presents the data.  Try adding the following code right after you import pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
```