# Why does pandas identify string "NaN" (a nitride of sodium) as a missing value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a set of chemical formulae (and some other properties) saved in a csv file. One of these formulae is ***NaN***, an unstable nitride. However, pandas identifies this as a missing value when loading from a csv file. Below is a simple reproducible example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'formula': ['BaO', 'NaN', 'NaN3']})

>>> df
  formula
0     BaO
1     NaN
2    NaN3
```

Let's get the data type of each of these formulae.

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(type(row.formula))

<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

This is fine. Now, we save this dataframe to a csv file and reload.

```
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
df_csv = pd.read_csv('data.csv') # same df loaded from csv

>>> df_csv
  formula
0     BaO
1     NaN
2    NaN3
```

`df_csv` looks identical to `df`, except when I check the data type of these formulae, I find ***NaN*** is identified as a missing numerical data point (`np.nan`).

```
for idx, row in df_csv.iterrows():
    print(type(row.formula))

<class 'str'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'str'>
```

This produces errors during my further processing steps. I don't want to remove the compound ***NaN*** from the database. How do I make sure ***NaN*** is not identified as a missing value, but as a string when loading data from a csv file?

I have tried `df_csv['formula']= df_csv['formula'].astype(str)` but this converts ***NaN*** to ***nan***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import pandas dataframe column as string not int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293810/import-pandas-dataframe-column-as-string-not-int)

Comment: This is will likely work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952142/prevent-pandas-from-interpreting-na-as-nan-in-a-string

Comment: @JeffUK I just tried this. The accepted answer does not work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [pandas documentation for read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), 'NaN' is one of default missing value indicators.

If you're sure there are no missing values in your csv file, you could simply pass an argument `na_filter = False` to your `read_csv()` call to stop missing value parse.

Otherwise, you could use `keep_default_na = False` to exclude the default values and specify your own with `na_values` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Set `na_filter` to `False` when using `pandas.read_csv` usage example

```
import io
import pandas as pd
csv_data = io.StringIO("formula\nBaO\nNaN\nNaN3\n")
df = pd.read_csv(csv_data, na_filter=False)
print(df['formula'].notna())
```

output

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: formula, dtype: bool
```

For brevity sake I used `io.StringIO` providing file with content same as argument used in `io.StringIO` will give same result.